# How to make robot stops when detects obstacle (C++, Raspberry PI, TCP communication)

Tags: c++, tcp, raspberry-pi, tcpclient, tcpserver

I need help. I've made a robot that finds the shortest path from point A to point B and it works perfectly. Now I want to implement an ultrasonic sensor on this robot so it can detect obstacles in front of it. When it detects the obstacle the robot should stop moving and wait until the obstacle is removed. I'm controlling the robot using TCP server/client communication (the robot is the client ). Now, like this, the robot does just the first movement and then stops even if there's no obstacle in front of it. The controlling and all the algorithm is done on the Server (PC) the client (Raspberry Pi) just executes the commands. Now, the idea is while the robot is travelling from point A to point B IF it detects any obstacle in front of him the robot should stop and wait until the obstacle is removed, but it should send also something to the server to stop the program i.e not to be executed, to wait until the robot sends another signal that obstacle has been removed.

I hope you get the idea. Here you have the client code and part of the server code where I do all this controlling stuff (these are the functions), but It doesn't work as I said properly. Also, I don't know how to debug it.

This is the client code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "libSonar.h"

enum class PacketType : char {
    ROBOT_STUCK = '1',
    ROBOT_UNSTUCK = '2'
};

using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for()
using namespace std::chrono; 

int trigger = 28;
int echo = 29;

int measureDistance()
{
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
        cout << "Initialization problem - measureDistance() " << endl;

    Sonar sonar;
    sonar.init(trigger, echo);

    int distance = 0;

    distance = sonar.distance(30000);
    sleep_for(nanoseconds(10));

    return distance;
}
string appendHeader(PacketType type, const string& packet) {
    string header = string(1, static_cast<char>(type));
    return header + packet;
}

bool checkForObstacles(int socket, int instructionNumber) 
{
    wiringPiSetup();

    // Controlling the motors from here
    softPwmCreate(0, 0, 255);
    softPwmCreate(4, 0, 255);

    string packetContents = appendHeader(PacketType::ROBOT_STUCK, to_string(instructionNumber));
    constexpr int MIN_DISTANCE = 5;

    int distance = measureDistance();
    //cout << "Distance: " << distance << endl;
    if (distance >= MIN_DISTANCE)
        return false;

    softPwmWrite(0, LOW);
    softPwmWrite(4, LOW);

    int sendRes = send(socket, packetContents.c_str(), packetContents.size() + 1, 0);
    delay(1000);

    while(distance < MIN_DISTANCE) 
    {
        delay(10); // re-measure after 10ms. Adjust to what you prefer
        distance = measureDistance();
    }

    packetContents = appendHeader(PacketType::ROBOT_UNSTUCK, "");
    sendRes = send(socket, packetContents.c_str(), packetContents.size() + 1, 0);
    delay(1000);


    return true;
}

int main()
{
    //  Create a socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //  Create a hint structure for the server we're connecting with
    int port = 54000;
    string ipAddress = "192.168.1.3";
    sockaddr_in hint;

    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);
    //  Connect to the server on the socket
    int connectRes = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connectRes == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[4096];

    memset(buf, 0, 4096);

    int CountReceived = 0;

    while(true)
    {   
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);       

        string received = string(buf, bytesReceived);   // receiving string from the Server
        CountReceived++;

        cout << "String: " << received << endl;

        string a = received.substr(0,3);        // Getting substrings from the string
        string b = received.substr(3,1);
        string c = received.substr(4,1);

        string d = received.substr(5,3);
        string e = received.substr(8,1);
        string f = received.substr(9,1);

        string g = received.substr(10,4);

        int enA = stoi(a);                  // converting substrings to integers so I can control the motors
        int in1 = stoi(b);
        int in2 = stoi(c);

        int enB = stoi(d);
        int in3 = stoi(e);
        int in4 = stoi(f);

        int t = stoi(g);                    // Time needed to work motors

        cout << ">>> " << enA << endl;  
        cout << ">>> " << in1 << endl;
        cout << ">>> " << in2 << endl;

        cout << ">>> " << enB << endl;
        cout << ">>> " << in3 << endl;
        cout << ">>> " << in4 << endl;

        cout <<">>> " << t << endl;

        // Pins for controlling the motors
        int enableA = 0;
        int input1 = 2;
        int input2 = 3;

        int enableB = 4;
        int input3 = 5;
        int input4 = 6;

        wiringPiSetup();

        // Controlling the motors from here
        softPwmCreate(enableA, 0, 255);
        pinMode(input1, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(input2, OUTPUT);

        softPwmCreate(enableB, 0, 255);
        pinMode(input3, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(input4, OUTPUT);

        softPwmWrite(enableA, enA);
        digitalWrite(input1, in1);
        digitalWrite(input2, in2);

        softPwmWrite(enableB, enB);
        digitalWrite(input3, in3);
        digitalWrite(input4, in4);

        //delay(t);

        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        while(true) 
        {
            auto now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(now-start).count();
            int remaining = t - (int) elapsed;

            if (remaining < 0)
                break;
            if (checkForObstacles(sock, CountReceived))
                continue;

            delay(min(remaining, 25)); // replace 25 with how often you want to check the distance
        }


        softPwmWrite(enableA, LOW);
        softPwmWrite(enableB, LOW);
        delay(1000);

        received.clear();
    }

    //  Close the socket
    close(sock);
    return 0;

}
```

And here's the servers code:

```cpp
enum class PacketType : char {
    ROBOT_STUCK = '1',
    ROBOT_UNSTUCK = '2'
};

std::string receivePacket(SOCKET socket) 
{
    constexpr int bufLen = 4096;
    static char buf[bufLen];

    int bytesReceived = recv(socket, buf, bufLen, 0);
    Sleep(100);
    return std::string(buf, bytesReceived);
}

PacketType getPacketHeader(const std::string& packet) 
{
    return static_cast<PacketType>(packet[0]);
}

void waitForUnstuck(SOCKET socket) 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        std::string packet = receivePacket(socket);
        if (getPacketHeader(packet) == PacketType::ROBOT_UNSTUCK)
            return;
    }
}

void receivePackets(SOCKET socket) 
{
    std::string packet = receivePacket(socket);

    cout << "Received: " << packet << endl;

    switch (getPacketHeader(packet)) 
    {
    case PacketType::ROBOT_STUCK:
        waitForUnstuck(socket);
        break;
    }
}

void move(SOCKET clientSocket, std::string str)
{
    send(clientSocket, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1, 0);
    Sleep(4000);
    str.clear();
}
```

I hope you understand the idea and I will appreciate if you want and have time to help me.

Comment: _but it should send also something to the server to stop the program i.e not to be executed, to wait until the robot sends another signal that obstacle has been removed._ Stop the server program? -> How should it receive the other message to continue? Stop the robot program (on Pi)? -> How should the robot process sensor input? Stop the robot motion? -> Just send the robot the command to switch off motor power. IMHO, you exposed too much code. It might be Complete but Minimal? Furthermore, I believe it's a design question but not a code question.

Comment: At a previous company, we bought a large number of those Lego robot sets. As it turns out, debugging these projects is a good learning experience even for experienced software engineers. From this question, it appears you are much less experienced. In particular, you seem to have issues in separating concerns. You're dumping far too much code on us, with no clear problem statement.

Comment: @MSalters This is not a Lego robot.

Comment: @Scheff I know this is a lot of code, but I don't know what to do that's why I'm here. I want to finish this, but don't know how. I posted the whole client code so you can see clearly what's going on. As I said right now with this kind of code the robot stops even if there's no obstacle in front.

Comment: @Dawid: Obviously. The Pi is a giveaway. The architecture problems are similar, though. You need a proper layered architecture. That allows you to first isolate the layer in which you have a problem.

Comment: Did you debug your concept? It's probably not quite easy to do this step by step - especially the part on Pi. However, there is still the possibility to insert print output (may be, guarded with `#ifdef _DEBUG` and `#endif`) to get a clue what happens in the loops.

Comment: @Scheff I didn't try to debug, because I'm not sure how to do that right now.

Comment: @Scheff I think the problem is with communication. Because, when I don't communicate with the server for the obstacles, when I put an obstacle in front of the robot it stops and when I remove the obstacle it continues, but this way the program on the server is running and I have no control over it.

Comment: _Because, when I don't communicate with the server for the obstacles, when I put an obstacle in front of the robot it stops and when I remove the obstacle it continues_ In this case, sensor and action are handled on Pi - without server involved. For me, it sounds whether you have to decide what is responsible for what -> still believe it's a design issue. (Or I mis-understood your problem.) Concerning debugging: I suggested output of diagnostics. That's what is usually called ["Print Debugging"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Debugging on the server or client side? And where, more precisely?

Comment: On that side where you think the problem is (or on both sides if in doubt). _And where, more precisely?_ No idea. I didn't read your complete code - it's too much. If I've such issues in my code, I think about which part of code could go wrong to show the effect which is observable. Then, I debug (or insert print output) to prove that "hypothesis" right or wrong. (Repeating this until I found the issue or give up. The latter is rarely an option.) ;-)

Comment: Needless to say, that a pre-condition is: You have a clear imagination of how things should work (at least, in theory).

Comment: @Scheff Hmmm, I don't want to give up immediately I want to try to solve this issue. But, right now I don't see any progress. :(

Comment: Heads up. Sometimes it may drive you crazy. If I get the feeling my brain might burst, I start to skribble sketches on paper or, even better, in Powerpoint. (The latter could become part of doc. later.) ;-)